# Ka always zeros in MTL file, reflectance and translucency coeffs also missing

Tags: materials, objects, export

I'm exporting a model from Blender into OBJ and MTL files. When I look at the generated MTL file I see that the "Ka" component of the material is all zeros, and there is no information about the reflectance and translucency of the material either. Have a look:

```
newmtl BigWall
Ns 15.000000
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ks 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Here the Kd and Ks colours have the correct value (all white) but the Ka is set to black.

I've seen that the `illum` statement can provide some hints on whether reflectance is used, but it does not give me any coefficients.

So how can I make Blender export the ambient coefficient or an ambient colour to this file? And from where can I take the coefficients of reflectance and translucency?

Thanks.

**BTW:** I found these similar questions here but they were not answered, I hope to run with better luck:

- [Blender not exporting Ambient Coefficient in .MTL](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5154/blender-not-exporting-ambient-coefficient-in-mtl)
- [Export Wavefront .mtl file — Where is the reflectance coefficient](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2904/export-wavefront-mtl-file-where-is-the-reflectance-coefficient)

**EDIT:** Blender's documentation [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Wavefront_OBJ#Export_Options) claims to be able to export ambient colour and shading settings like transparency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the ambient color is black.

If you change it to something else in *Properties > World > Ambient Color*, then it works as expected:

[image]